# Replace same string with different one every time

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that contains same *value* in different place. For instance:

> Salam. Men yaxsiyam sen necesen? Sen ne vaxt geleceksen? Sen oralarda ne edirsen?

How can I change this string like below?

> Salam. Men yaxsiyam sen1 necesen? Sen2 ne vaxt geleceksen? Sen3 oralarda ne edirsen?

P.S I searched but couldn't find any source.

I also tried `string.Replace()`, `StringBuilder.Replace()`, `Regex.Replace()` methods. But didn't reached to result.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: What is your pattern exactly? Do you wanna get only concat `sen` or `Sen` with numbers starts `1`? What about `sEn` or `seN` etc..?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman the codes I want to do this, are completely wrong. That's why I don't want to share them. But I posted that which methods I tried.

Comment: All methods you've mentioned would work for your case. Clearly [C# Replace does not work](https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+replace+does+not+work) but it should not stop you... Please post code you've tried (along with articles you found that explain particular approach).

Comment: @SonerGönül: pattern is `Sen`. not `sen` or `sEN` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use `Regex.Replace` for this. You can use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) with `MatchEvaluator` (`Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, MatchEvaluator evaluator)`). This method replaces all strings that match a specified regular expression with a string returned by a [MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate.  For example:

```
int i = 0;
string s = "Salam. Men yaxsiyam sen necesen? Sen ne vaxt geleceksen? Sen oralarda ne edirsen?";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, "(?i)sen", match => match.Value + i++));
```

Outputs:

> Salam. Men yaxsiyam sen0 necesen1? Sen2 ne vaxt geleceksen3? Sen4 oralarda ne edirsen5?

But this is just an example. You can do more.
**Edit**:
This regex (`\s(?i)sen(?=\s)`) with starting `i` at 1 will give exactly the same results you want.

Comment: `geleceksen` should not be replaced.

Comment: what's the `"(?i)sen"` ? Can you explain please?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not doing exactly what he wants, but he can change this a little and get his desired result.

Comment: "(?i)sen" is the regular expression pattern. "(?i)" means you are ignoring cases. So it matches "sen" or "Sen" or "sEN" etc.. But idk if that's what you want. You can change the regular expression.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski, I have edited my answer. It will now give the results you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Regex.Replace` will do the work, you can use groups if you want to match only full words.

```
var str = "Salam. Men yaxsiyam sen necesen? Sen ne vaxt geleceksen? Sen oralarda ne edirsen?";
int indexer = 0;
var str2 = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<pre>[^\w])(?<content>sen)(?<post>[^\w])", m => m.Groups["pre"].Value + m.Groups["content"].Value + (indexer++) + m.Groups["post"].Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```